# How do I properly store raw byte data in XML and recover it?

Tags: c++, qt

Using C++ and Qt, I need to store some raw byte data (an unsigned char array) in a QDomElement (XML node), and then recover it later so that I can compare it to the raw data that is written directly to a different binary file. During testing, I noticed my solution works ~85% of the time, but comparing the recovered data and the raw data read from file seems to fail occasionally.  The code snippets below illustrate the Qt methods I am currently using. I have very little knowledge of different character encodings and what I need to look out for in that regard, so I am assuming my mistake has something to do with that.

Storing the raw data in XML:

```
QDomElement myElement;
unsigned char rawData[ DATA_LEN ];
foo( rawData );  // upon return, rawData now contains the data I want to store in XML
QByteArray dataByteArray( reinterpret_cast< char * >( rawData ) );
QString dataStr( dataByteArray.toBase64() );
QByteArray excluded = " /():|+,.=[]_^{}";
myElement.setAttribute( "Data", QUrl::toPercentEncoding( dataStr, excluded ) );
```

Recovering the data from XML and comparing to raw data read from binary file (the memcmp() occasionally fails):

```
unsigned char recoveredData[ DATA_LEN ];
QString dataStr = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding( stringFromXmlNode.toUtf8() );
QByteArray dataByteArray = QByteArray::fromBase64( dataStr.toAscii() );
memcpy( recoveredData, reinterpret_cast< unsigned char * >( dataByteArray.data() ), DATA_LEN );

unsigned char dataFromFile[ DATA_LEN ];
fread( dataFromFile, 1, DATA_LEN, filePtr );
if( 0 != memcmp( dataFromFile, recoveredData, DATA_LEN ) )
{
    return false;
}
```

I am restricted to Qt 4.8, so please refrain from any Qt5-specific solutions if possible, thanks!

Comment: This question needs much more details: You should try to debug the problem yourself in your mind *based on your question*. Then add anything you find missing. Questions which immediately rise are: what is the input data? How does it look when converted to base64? How does it look in the final XML? Does that `toPercentEncoding` actually change what it looks like in XML? How does it look after you decode it with `fromBase64`. Note that QByteArray has very handy `toHex` method.

Comment: The input data is 24 bytes of unsigned char data that is randomly generated. A sample of what the base64 encoding looks like is this: "PuB5lfj0ZElvHJjir6dVeF1tp422wQoYIgW9mSnp". That is how it appears in the final XML for this case as well. The percent encoding may not actually change anything, depending on the case.

Comment: Well, if encoding data gives `PuB5lfj0ZElvHJjir6dVeF1tp422wQoYIgW9mSnp` and decoding gives different data, that narrows down the problem a lot. Try encode same data with some online or command line base64 tool to see which.

Comment: @hyde I have done some further debugging, looking at the data at all stages of conversion and recovery over several tests of my application (since it is not reliably reproducable 100% of the time), and it seems that my problem is occurring before any encoding takes place. In all cases that failed, it seems that my raw data is getting truncated during the reinterpret_cast to a char *. Of course, this doesn't make things any clearer to me, but at least I know it isn't Qt or ASCII encoding related...

Comment: Ah, does your raw data contain 0 bytes? If it does, you need to pass it's length, and use methods which take that length instead of taking C string (which are 0-terminated).

Comment: @hyde Doh! Thank you for giving my brain the kick it needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state the bytes are random, so they can contain 0 bytes. Byte value 0 is string terminator in C-style strings. This line in your code initializes `QByteArray` from such string:

```
QByteArray dataByteArray( reinterpret_cast< char * >( rawData ) );
```

Solution is to also pass length of `rawData` and use [this constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-1).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an XML CDATA section.

Look at `QDomCDATASection`

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdomcdatasection.html

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Do you mean I should use that instead of what I am doing above, or use that in addition to what I am already doing?

Comment: Instead of. CDATA sections are the correct way to embed binary data inside of XML. Don’t try to encode it and put it in an attribute.

Comment: You might want to Base64 encode the binary, but still use CDATA for the result of that

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [QDataStream](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html), which can define the byte order (important if exchanging data across different platforms) and the versioning?

From the Qt 4.8 documentation page:

> A data stream cooperates closely with a QIODevice. A QIODevice represents an input/output medium one can read data from and write data to. The QFile class is an example of an I/O device.
>
> Example (write binary data to a stream):
>
> ```
> QFile file("file.dat"); 
> file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); 
> QDataStream out(&file);   // we will serialize the data into the file
> out << QString("the answer is");   // serialize a string 
> out << (qint32)42;  // serialize an integer
> ```
>
> Example (read binary data from a stream):
>
> ```
> QFile file("file.dat"); 
> file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); 
> QDataStream in(&file);    // read the data serialized from the file 
> QString str;
> qint32 a;
> in >> str >> a;  // extract "the answer is" and 42
> ```
>
> Each item written to the stream is written in a predefined binary
>   format that varies depending on the item's type. Supported Qt types
>   include QBrush, QColor, QDateTime, QFont, QPixmap, QString, QVariant
>   and many others. **For the complete list of all Qt types supporting data
>   streaming see [Serializing Qt Data Types](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html)**.

You can read/write your XML Data with QDataStream and import them in the QDomDocument structure with the QDomDocument function `setContent()` and `toByteArray()`.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to storing binary data bytes into a DOM *element*. Perhaps you could expand the answer to show how to link these?

Comment: Thanks, but a QDataStream will not work for me due to other restrictions.